# Date Comparison in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to compare date in javascript with time I have used below code for comparison

```
                 var pfrmdt = Date.parse(frmdt);
                 var ptodt = Date.parse(todt);
                 alert(pfrmdt)
                 alert(ptodt)


                   if(pfrmdt <= ptodt)
                     {
                        return true;
                     }     
                    else{
                          alert(msg); 
                          focusCtrl.value="";
                          focusCtrl.focus();
                        }
```

but its comparing with date only not with time

Comment: It's hard to tell  , you dont show the `frmdt` value

Comment: what is the value of `frmdt` and `todt`

Comment: Try comparing getTime() for both the date instances like: if (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime())

Comment: Just create the date object by using one of these ways https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and then  you can compare dates.

Comment: As as it is written in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) `dateString` argument of `Date.parse` method must be **a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date**.
Can you specify example values of `frmdt` and `todt` variables in you example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
var today = new Date();
var otherDay = new Date("04/01/2013");
alert(today >= otherDay);
```

Or

```
new Date('1945/05/09').valueOf() < new Date('2011/05/09').valueOf()
```